# How do I ensure local iis access security?

Tags: iis, firewall, cloudflare

I have windows 2008 R2 server. It is located behind a firewall called Fortigate.

I need to access an application on local iis from outside.

I opened a free account on cloudflare for this. I forwarded the A record of localsite.mydomain.com to my own ip address.

I opened a port in Firewall and forwarded it to my server.

My aim is only to be able to access the port on the server from localsite.mydomain.com, other than that, by typing the ip address, port scanning programs and so on. I don't want it to be accessed.

I thought of typing the cloudflare ip address from the server's firewall, but the cloudflare ip address is constantly changing. How can I do it?

Comment: You can find all kinds of such information in Cloudflare documentation, https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201897700-Allowing-Cloudflare-IP-addresses BTW, the biggest security issue for you at this moment is to use the end-of-life Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Hello, I can add these ip ranges to the firewall before windows server. But when I ping localsite.mydomain.com, the ip I get is 104.21.xx.xxx But there is no such ip address in this list. (https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/)

Comment: Because what you get from `nslookup` is where external HTTP requests from web browsers arrive (the arrow goes into the reverse proxy) but the actual Cloudflare requests are generated from one of the addresses in that range (the arrow(s) goes out of the reverse proxy), https://www.cloudflare.com/en-ca/learning/cdn/glossary/reverse-proxy/